# do you need to login - using `az devops login` - when AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT is set?

Tags: azure, authentication, command-line-interface, devops, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Do I still need to login using `az devops login` in cli to work on Azure DevOps when I already have PAT set using environment variable?

I tried the code below on three workstations but it keeps failing on third workstation:

1. Ubuntu running in Azure
2. Ubuntu running locally in the container in my laptop
3. WSL (Ubuntu) running locally in my laptop

```sh
export AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT=******************
organization="https://dev.azure.com/myorg/"
az devops project list --organization $organization
```

Note that I **am able to retrieve** the project list from the first two "workstations" without invoking `az devops login`, but **unable to retrieve** so on my WSL, and I am getting the following error message:

> Before you can run Azure DevOps commands, you need to run the login command(az login if using AAD/MSA identity else az devops login if using PAT token) to setup credentials.  Please see https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth for more information.

Any idea of what would contribute to this inconsistency?